# Error with mvn package on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am having trouble packaging a maven module on Jenkins. This problem does not occur when I package the module locally. I have a module which for the sake of this post can be referred to as *moduleA*. I also have a common module which contains objects that are used by *moduleA* and *moduleB*. This module's name is *common*. I have a dependency listing for *common* in the *moduleA* pom.xml. The project also contains dependencies taken from our private nexus repository. The problem that is occurring, is that when maven is downloading all the dependencies on Jenkins, it is looking for *common* on the Nexus repo. Below is some relevant information. **Is there a way I can resolve this, short of deploying the common module to the Nexus**?

**Maven Command**

```
mvn -pl sub_module_name package -X -U --also-make-dependents
```

**Repositories in POM**

```
         <repository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>${our.nexus.instance}</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <url>${our.nexus.instance}</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

**Jenkins Error Message**

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project moduleA: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project my.artifact:moduleA:jar:1.0.01-
SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact my.artifact:common:jar:1.0.01-
SNAPSHOT in nexus-snapshots 
({our.nexus.instance}) -> 
[Help 1]

    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to 
execute goal on project moduleA: Could not resolve dependencies for project
 my.artifact:moduleA:jar:1.0.01-SNAPSHOT: Could not find 
artifact my.artifact:common:jar:1.0.01-SNAPSHOT in nexus-
snapshots ({our.nexus.instance})
```

Comment: Have you uploaded (`mvn deploy`) your common library to your nexus instance? The error here suggests that it doesn't exist there.

Comment: I have not, and in my experience, I shouldn't have to. In other projects I have avoided uploading common modules to the nexus by installing it in the reactor build. As mentioned, this also works locally because of the "--also-make-dependents".

Comment: Can you query the `{our.nexus.instance}` and seek if is includes the `my.artifact:common:jar:1.0.01-
SNAPSHOT` jar anyway? Since the error points that very prominently. And this might not be failing in your local since the `.m2` in your local might already be having the SNAPSHOT jar available.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say to him @nullpointer sure the error is that one. The artifact isn't on the repository. You are completely right it works local because at some point he built the module local which make it available at the `.m2` repository (which is local)

Comment: Well, @tramstheman is asking "short of deploying the common module to the Nexus", so it sounds like he prefer not to deploy and just build the module locally. I've also seen the common module pattern around at my workplace as well, but I myself do not know what the issue might be around building common locally and it not being found...

Comment: I just checked, common is not in the Nexus, nor is it in my local .m2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your maven command. I recommend you change your command to the following

```
mvn -pl common,moduleA install package -X -U
```

This ensures that the common module is installed before moduleA is packaged.

Comment: This worked, however I am going to continue searching for a solution in which I can use --also-make-dependents